# Visual Basic 2D Array Issue

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I currently am having some trouble trying to get my program to work with a 2D array. I had it working earlier with a 1D array but I am totally lost now that I have to make these changes.

Below is what I currently have as my 2D array and the code that I thought would work for spitting out a letter grade but does not give me anything. Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private strGrades(,) As String = {{"900", "A"},
                                     {"815", "B"},
                                     {"750", "C"},
                                     {"700", "D"},
                                     {"0", "F"}}
 Dim strGradeSearch As String
    Dim intRow As Integer

    strGradeSearch = txtGrade.Text

    For intRow = 0 To 4
        If intRow > strGrades.GetUpperBound(0) Then
            strGrades(0, intRow) = strGradeSearch
            intRow += 1
        End If
    Next intRow

    If intRow <= strGrades.GetUpperBound(0) Then
        lblLetter.Text = strGrades(intRow, 0)
    End If
```

Comment: Firstly, do you have to use a 2D array? Beginner classes love using them early on in situations where they are simply not appropriate, because the student doesn't have the more advanced knowledge to do the right thing.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The assignment asks for it specifically otherwise I had other ways I would have done this myself also..

Comment: Secondly, have you debugged your code? Noone should be posting a question here without debugging first. You don't generally fix issues with code just by reading it. You need to run it and watch it in action. Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it line by line. You should know exactly what should happen at each step so you should be able to tell exactly when things go wrong. Even if you can't fix the issue yourself, at least you can provide us with all the relevant details, including what you expected, what happened and what data was in use at the time.

Comment: Never used a breakpoint before, I will try looking into that. Also I never really had to debug it since most of what we do is somewhat easy and I understand it enough to get through the assignment.

Comment: Unfortunately, far too many beginner courses/classes ignore debugging altogether. They teach people how to write code but not how fix the inevitable issues that arise. Debugging is an essential skill so learning it sooner rather than later will stand you in good stead. The problem is that we all assume that our code does what we intended but often the issue is obvious when you see what the code actually does as it executes.

Comment: Yeah, not one section of our text had gone over any sort of debugging. But looking back at what I have, I think I am completely wrong in what I'm trying to do. I would look more into the text but it does not bring up anything that I see of use to this assignment and end up resorting to google for assistance.

Comment: Please ensure your code is [mcve]. I have just loaded this into Visual Studio - can't declare a private in local scope (but can at a module scope - so where is the function declaration?), txtGrade and lblLetter are not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take all the following as positive comments :-)

OK. looking at your code, there are tbh several issues. You're trying to treat strings as numbers. While a string can contain what looks like a number, it only contains a string of characters that happen to be numbers. They make sense to use, but to a computer, they aren't. There is often stuff that VB does in the background to try and make life easier, but to be honest, it can be a pain.

When comparing something like grades, you need to compare actual numbers, not strings that contain numbers. You'll potentially get unexpected results. You need to get the computer to convert the string to a number. See below.

Your loop wont actually do anything because the `If` statement will never execute the code inside it because `intRow` will never be greater than the last element of the array. Anyhow.. Onwards.

A way to convert strings to numbers is to user the `Val` function, though this "old" VB. The current way is to use `Integer.Parse`. Have a look at [this link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse-vbnet) for some basic information about it.

Lets walk through what you want to do.

1. Get the string in the textbox.
2. Convert the string to a number.
3. Loop through the array and for each element, get the number stored as a string and convert it to a number and then compare it to the grade number.
4. If the grade is greater than any of the values, make a note of the
   letter linked to the grade and stop searching through the loop.
5. Assign the letter  that was found to the label.

The following code should do this

```
    Dim strGrades(,) As String = {{"900", "A"},
                                     {"815", "B"},
                                     {"750", "C"},
                                     {"700", "D"},
                                     {"0", "F"}}
    Dim intGradeSearch As Integer
    Dim strGradeLetter As String = ""
    intGradeSearch = Integer.Parse(TxtGrade.Text)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        If intGradeSearch >= Integer.Parse(strGrades(i, 0)) Then
            strGradeLetter = strGrades(i, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    LblLetter.Text = strGradeLetter
End Sub
```

You dont need to check `intRow` after the loop has finished, because in this case, at some point in the loop, a grade letter will always be found if the number in the textbox is greater than or equal to a number in the array.

If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.